# Xbox 360 controller on PC only indentified with the play and charge

Tags: battery, xbox360, game-controller

I have a different problem than most with my XBOX 360 Wireless controller on the PC. I have the a wireless receptor connector and the Play and Charge kit. IT is an original Microsoft 360 controller.

My problem is, if I disconnect the play and charge the controller stops working. I thought the obvious, that it would be that it is not charged, but playing the home button show on the pc that it is full charge. Any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: If you see the status while its not plugged in, then your pc sees the device, the play and charge cable only charges the controller it does not transfer ANY data, zero, absolutely nothing.  I have used the device for 8 years on my PC.

Comment: I know that ramhound. And the thing is, the PC sees nothing without the play and charge. So my first thought was that the battery. But with the play and charge it reports as 100% .

Comment: You said it was 100% without being plugged in though...have you tried changing the batteries, use normal AAs as a test, don't use a pack.  It's going to show 100% while plugged in that's normal...